# Kafka Connect SMT to add Kafka header fields

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I need to find or write an SMT that will add header fields to a request.  The request is missing some type fields and I want to add them.

How exactly do you add a header within an SMT all I have seen are just record transforms like below but what if its the header I want to change or add a field to?

```
   private R applySchemaless(R record) {

   final Map<String, Object> value = requireMap(operatingValue(record), PURPOSE);
  // record.headers.add(Header)  but how do I define the header
  // or record.headers.add(String, Schema) but I am not sure how to define Schema? 
  final Map<String, Object> updatedValue = new HashMap<>(value);

  updatedValue.put(fieldName, getRandomUuid());
  

  return newRecord(record, null, updatedValue);
  
}
```

Comment: So I see record.headers().add(Header) but Header is an abstract type

Comment: How do I create an Instance of Header.  there is also record.headers().add(String, Schema) but schema also abstract how is this specified?

Comment: You'd want to use this - https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/SchemaBuilder.html

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: Any suggestions for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63311462/kafka-connect-smt-applywithschema-requires-struct-error

Comment: Got a new problem I sucessfully put TypeId in the header but the deserializer in Spring Kafka still says no type in headers found or default type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
Headers headers = new ConnectHeaders();
headers.add(myKey, myValue, mySchema);
headers.forEach(h -> record.headers().add(h));
```

ConnectHeaders info can be found here - https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/header/Headers.html

Comment: I see there is a headers.addString(s1,s2).  Do you have any information on constructing the schema object which seems to be an abstract interface.

Comment: Headers must come from the connect package there is also a headers in common

Comment: It worked perfectly. Now I am onto custom Deserializers!