# Kafka Connect SMT ApplyWithSchema requires struct error

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have deployed a sample from confluent https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-insert-uuid for adding simple UUID field but I am getting an error that it requires struct.  I am applying this within Debezium MySQLConnector

```
  Only Struct objects supported for [adding UUID to record], found: 
  java.lang.String\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.util.Requirements.requireStruct(Requirements.java:52)
```

What is a minimalist applyWithSchema method that just returns the record as is? I am trying to debug and need a HelloWorld SMT without any errors that have to apply methods including applyWithSchema

I think this is probably most simple for the application but need for applyWithSchema

```java
Override
public R apply(R record) {
    
    return record.newRecord(
            record.topic(), record.kafkaPartition(),
            record.keySchema(), record.key(),
            record.valueSchema(), record.value(),
            record.timestamp()
    );
}

Override
public R applyWithSchema(R record) {
    // what is minimal transform here??
}
```

I just need these functions to run without error now, as I am making a change to record.headers().add() only.

Here is the applyWithSchema method that gives the error:

```java
private R applyWithSchema(R record) {
    // FAILS HERE!
    final Struct value = requireStruct(operatingValue(record), PURPOSE);

    Schema updatedSchema = schemaUpdateCache.get(value.schema());
    if(updatedSchema == null) {
        updatedSchema = makeUpdatedSchema(value.schema()); 

        final Struct updatedValue = new Struct(updatedSchema);

        for (Field field : value.schema().fields()) {
         // updatedValue.put(field.name(), value.get(field));
        }

        //updatedValue.put(fieldName, getRandomUuid());

        return newRecord(record, updatedSchema, updatedValue);
    }
```

Comment: You can use the `Hoist` transforms to get a Struct.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly the issue is with your connector transformation config order, connector will apply these SMT operations in synchronize order when you are defining it. If you are expecting a struct or a native information for your custom SMT make sure previous SMT won't be mutating the natural state.

```
"transforms":"SMT1, SMT2, CustomSMT3",
```