# Kafka: Replicate topic A to topic B while applying a transformation to the records

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I need to mirror records from a topic on a cluster A to a topic on cluster B **while adding a field onto the record as they are proxied (eg. `InsertField`)**.

I am not controlling cluster A (but could require changes) and have full control of cluster B.

I know that cluster A is sending serialised JSON.

I am using the [MirrorMaker API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0) with Kafka connect to do the mirroring and I am trying to use `InsertField` transformation to add data on the record as they are proxied.

My configuration looks like that:

```
connector.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector
topics=.*
source.cluster.alias=upstream
source.cluster.bootstrap.servers=source:9092
target.cluster.bootstrap.servers=target:9092

# ByteArrayConverter to avoid MirrorMaker to re-encode messages
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter


transforms=InsertSource1
transforms.InsertSource1.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value
transforms.InsertSource1.static.field=test_inser
transforms.InsertSource1.static.value=test_value
name=somerandomname
```

This code will fail with an error stating:

> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Only Struct objects
> supported for [field insertion]

Is there a way to achieve this without writing a custom transform (I am using Python and I am not familiar with Java)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you use `ByteArrayConverter`? Please try to use `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter`. In your case Kafka Connect interprets your data just as a byte array (unstructured data), so it's not posible to modify the data (e.g. inserting field)

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander Thanks for the input, Alexander. I think the idea of using the `ByteArrayConverter` is so that message do not get re-serialized when passing through the connector. I use `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter` (which the default on my environment) then the value comes out serialized twice. Which yield messages like this:```
schema: { type: bytes, optional: false },
payload: eyJ0aW1lIjogMTYwNjUyNTAxNSwgInZhbHVlIjogOH0=``` (Here payload should be JSON object)

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander I've reformulated my question to help making sense of my use case. Any input much appreciated

Comment: Thanks! How do you read replicated messages from cluster B?

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander For debugging purposes I use https://github.com/lensesio/kafka-topics-ui/releases to read topic content. The records are being produced by the confluent python client like so: `client.produce('topic_name', json.dumps(some_dict).encode('UTF-8'))`

Comment: Can you provide example of `some_dict`?

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander for the current that I am running it looks like this: `{"timestamp": 123123123, "value": 42 }`. So timestamp information and a value

Comment: You might want to read https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/#json-schemas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current version of `Apache Kafka` (2.6.0), you *cannot apply* [InsertField](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/insertfield.html) single message transformation (SMT) to `MirrorMaker 2.0` records.

**Explanation**

The [`MirrorMaker 2.0`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0) is based on `Kafka Connect` framework and, internally, the MirrorMaker 2.0 driver sets up [`MirrorSourceConnector`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.6/connect/mirror/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/mirror/MirrorSourceConnector.java).

Source connectors [apply SMT immediately](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.6/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/WorkerSourceTask.java#L339) after polling records (there are no converters (e.g. [`ByteArrayConverter`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.6/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/converters/ByteArrayConverter.java) or [`JsonConverter`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.6/connect/json/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/json/JsonConverter.java)) at this steps: they are used [after](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.6/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/WorkerSourceTask.java#L340) SMT has been applied).

The [`SourceRecord`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.6/connect/api/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/source/SourceRecord.java) value [are represented as a byte array](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.6/connect/mirror/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/mirror/MirrorSourceTask.java#L137-L141) with `BYTES_SCHEMA` [schema](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.6/connect/mirror/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/mirror/MirrorSourceTask.java#L240). At the same time `InsertField` transformation [requires](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.6/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/InsertField.java#L164) `Type.STRUCT` for records with schema.

So, since record can not be determine as [`Struct`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.6/connect/api/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/Struct.java), transformation is not applied.

**References**

1. [KIP-382: MirrorMaker 2.0](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0)
2. [How to Use Single Message Transforms in Kafka Connect](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-single-message-transformation-tutorial-with-examples/)

**Additional resources**

1. [Docker-compose playground for MirrorMaker 2.0](https://github.com/Iskuskov/kafka_mirror_maker_2_poc)

Answer (score 0):

As commented, the Byte Array converter has no Struct/Schema information, so therefore the transform you're using (adding a field) cannot be used.

This does not mean that no transforms can be used, however

---

If you're sending JSON messages, you must send schema and payload information.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am aware that ByteArrayConverter is the culprit here but MirrorMaker requires this to not re serialise the messages. So the question is how would one go about mirroring a stream while applying transforms on the way

Comment: I've updated the post to make the use case clearer.

Comment: You can't avoid decoding. You're expecting JSON to de-coded, then adding a field, then re-encoded

Comment: You could add a record header instead of a field, which is always serialized as a map

Comment: Is adding headers on a per-message basis possible with Kafka connect? I see a bunch of open PR but nothing in the documentatioin

Comment: headers are per-message, yes. I'm not sure there are existing ones, but [sample code is here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63293037/2308683)